# NodeJS vs Golang for REST API and implementing backend with it

Tags: node.js, rest, go, package, backend

I'm trying to know that which one is better amongst `Node` and `Golang`? what are the pros and cons for both of them. How does the `Golang` package ecosystem compares with `NPM` and is `Golang` mature enough for go in production? Whats the comparison between the learning curve of `Node` and `Golang`

Comment: I would advise Google to get answer for this. There might be articles which people have written after either in production experience or, by doing benchmarks. Stackoverflow is certainly not a great place for such open ended question to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do backend and REST with either Node or Golang, they're both great for that task. Why you would choose one over the other is highly dependent on the task you're trying to accomplish and the boundaries in which you must accomplish it in. When you get into the nitty-gritty of the two, you're really comparing apples and oranges. I prefer the opinionated nature of Go, it's focus on efficiency, and it's native concurrency. Overall I'm not really a javascript fan and backend created with it seems to be a square peg trying to be put in a round hole.